# Distribution transformation when having same mean and variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, random-variable, gamma-distribution

Is it possible to transform the distribution to Gaussian, with same mean and variance?

For example,

The Gamma RV. X with K=7.5 and theta=1.0.

--> The Gaussian RV. X' with not changing mean and variance.

I think it will be possible because they have similar shape.

But I don't know how it can be expressed mathematically.

Could you give me a little help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any two continuous distributions, it is possible to transform one into another. Suppose the two distributions have cumulative distribution functions $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ respectively. Further, suppose random variable $X$ is distributed according to $F_X(x)$. Then random variable
$$
Y = F_Y^{-1}(F_X(X))\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
is distributed according to $F_Y(y)$. In the expression (1) above, $F^{-1}_Y()$ is the inverse function of $F_Y()$.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps me :)